# How to pass variables in an awk

Tags: linux, awk

I need to pass some variable in the following awk cmd,

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[\$0]++;next}!(a[\$6])' "file1" "file2" > output
```

Instead of providing the value **6**, I need to pass it as a variable?

Comment: Did you read the manpage ? look at `-v` command line option

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script

Comment: Well, I checked the above post but it doesn't solved my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using `-v` to pass a variable to awk. Also note that if you use single quotes around the awk program, you don't want to escape the `$`s.

```
$ cat file1.txt
1
4

$ cat file2.txt
1,2
3,4

$ awk -F, -v i=1 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} !(a[$i])' file1.txt file2.txt
3,4

$ awk -F, -v i=2 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} !(a[$i])' file1.txt file2.txt
1,2
```